# Responsiveness through container width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsiveness

I am using bootstrap for responsive form layout. I am able to achieve responsive layout through bootstrap grid system (col-xs-.., col-md-.., etc..)
Here's the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xf93jnLw/2/

The issue is due to media queries, the form layout is getting adjusted through the screen view-port width, which Left nav width + form container width. And I am looking to adjust the responsiveness based on only form-container width. So that if I want to use this form-container in modal window, the form fields and labels should get adjust through the form-container width, and not the whole screen view-port. Is there any pure CSS solution for this?

Appreciate your responses...

HTML code:
    
        Left nav
    
    
      
        
          
              
            
                    
                        
                            Long sized label for testing:

```
                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Medium sized label:"><div class="content ng-binding">Medium sized label:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Short label:"><div class="content ng-binding">Short label:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Long sized label for testing:"><div class="content ng-binding">Long sized label for testing:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Medium sized label:"><div class="content ng-binding">Medium sized label:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Short label:"><div class="content ng-binding">Short label:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Long sized label for testing:"><div class="content ng-binding">Long sized label for testing:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Medium sized label:"><div class="content ng-binding">Medium sized label:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Short label:"><div class="content ng-binding">Short label:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Long sized label for testing:"><div class="content ng-binding">Long sized label for testing:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Medium sized label:"><div class="content ng-binding">Medium sized label:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Short label:"><div class="content ng-binding">Short label:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Long sized label for testing:"><div class="content ng-binding">Long sized label for testing:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Medium sized label:"><div class="content ng-binding">Medium sized label:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ers-field col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 ers-col-label">
                        <label class="ers-label" title="Short label:"><div class="content ng-binding">Short label:</div></label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 ers-col-field">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>                    

                <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.left-nav {float:left; background:purple; color:white; height:100%; width:10%;}
.form-container {float:left;width:85%; background:lightblue}
.ers-field {
  margin: 0 0 3px 0; }
  .ers-field .ers-label {
    padding: 8px 0 5px 5px;
    font: normal 13px Arial, sans-serif; }
    .ers-field .ers-label .required {
      color: #cc0000; }
    .ers-field .ers-label .content {
      max-width: 93%;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      white-space: nowrap;
      float: left; }
  .ers-field .ers-input {
    padding: 0 15px 0 5px; }

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .ers-col-field, .ers-col-label {
    padding: 0 5px; } }
@media (min-width: 1001px) {
  .ers-col-field, .ers-col-label {
    padding: 0 15px 0 5px; } }
```

Comment: I have a suggestion, why dont you just make your `form` horizontal and create two columns one for the left nav and one for the form itself instead of putting each element of the form in a column, its kinda messy if you ask me. If you want you I will provide a neat answer that might help you through this and future projects. Just tell say yes.

Comment: Also just put the labels above the `input` it would be better looking.

Comment: Yes please, I would like to have your answer/solution.

Comment: There please read my answer mate. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/okaje4c9/)

Check this out, Im not sure if this solves your problem but you might want to re-code your `HTML` and follow something like this. Not only it is neater but it is more standard and easier to maintain.

You can also check my answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086639/how-to-create-a-bootstrap-nested-grid/30094149#30094149) it might help you understand Bootstrap's Grid System more.

Comment: I appreciate your response. But as I am using bootstrap grid system, form layout is getting adjusted based on screen width e.g. @media (min-width: 1200px for col-lg-... etc. Is there any way I can set form layout through <div class="form-container"> width, as I will be using this form in many places, in modal widow or in partial section of the page  and I want label-field should be adjusted based on the form-container width rather that screen width.
Or any other logic if you can suggest?

Comment: What bootstrap version are you using mate? Have you checked this out yet? [GridSystem](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options). 

What I dont understand is : 
1. Why do you want the label positioned like that? Is it better if they are in the top of the `input`? @ajay

Comment: @ajay In my answer the width of the `form` is also adjusted based on the screen size. Bootstrap's grid system in ver. 3.3.4 is easy. Read this. [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30086639/how-to-create-a-bootstrap-nested-grid/30094149#30094149) 

For now I just dont understand why you want the form that way. But for now All I can suggest is use the grid system that I am suggesting. Sorry if I did not able to help you, but please just ask me if you need further help.