# How to create a Bootstrap nested Grid?

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to divide my page into two columns. I follow the sample code, it is still remain in one column. What should I do next? Thanks.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
           <table class="table table-bordered">
            <legend>Manage</legend>
          </table>
</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <legend>Special Functions</legend>
          </table>
</div>
        </div>
          </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works here ... http://www.bootply.com/2U4TjwqcKR Assuming of course that your window is wider than 992px as you are using the `-md-` classes

Comment: Are you sure your CSS file is being included at the right path?

Comment: yes. I am sure about the path. I am confused I see you code is working. But I donot know whats missing about mine.

Comment: It seems to me your path to the CSS file is the problem. I took the exact code and threw it on my local dev server and it worked fine. Try changing the path to `<link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">` and see if that helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The CSS file is the problem. I replace it. It works.

Comment: Just let me know if my answer helped you. :) @user3375421

Answer (score 3):

Consider this. Your code is totally correct except you missed some classes. See explanation below. You don't necessarily need your own `media-query` for the grid system.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <legend>Manage</legend>
            </table>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <legend>Special Functions</legend>
            </table>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**

In this line : `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">` you can change the `width` of the `div` based on grid-system of bootstrap. There are 4 classes on that div.

1. `col-lg-12` this class is recognize when the `width` screen is greater than `1200px`. You can change the number accordingly. `12` would be the full size of the grid system, `6` would be half of the full size of the grid system, `4` is 3/4 of the full size of the grid system etc.
2. `col-sm-12` is recognize when the screen `width` is equal or greater than `768px`. Same rule applies for the numbers.
3. `col-md-12` is recognize when the screen `width` is greater than `992px`. Same rule for the numbers.
4. `col-xs-12` si recognize if the screen `width` is less than `768px` thus mobile devices. All grid number here is equivalent to the full size of the grid system. For example if you use `col-xs-12` the width will be 100% same as when you use `col-xs-1` it will also be 100% same goes for 2, 3, 4, etc.

> You don't actually need to include all of these different classes, as Bootstrap will take whatever class you have, and apply it to any larger classes that are available. So effectively, you only set your minimum class (if all the others above it are the same) - [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3359782/lee)

You also might wanna consider Mr. Lee's comment. He is right. In any case that you need any `col` grid to be the same as other screen sizes, just take the minimum class. For example :

This is correct - 
`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">`

but this is better and shorter -
`<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">`

Bootstrap will take the minimum class and will apply it to other screen sizes or media queries.

Comment: I like your answer :)

Comment: You don't actually need to include all of these different classes, as Bootstrap will take whatever class you have, and apply it to any larger classes that are available. So effectively, you only set your minimum class (if all the others above it are the same).

Comment: No you don't. But just to be safe if in case you might need your page to be dynamic it is always better to have all this classes specially if you are developing a mobile friendly website. If you only use the minimum class it will be a problem if you need to customize the grid for larger devices and monitors, you will end up writing a custom `css` just to customize the grid system, while you can declare them immediately to avoid inconveniences in the future editing. Just my point and opinion, but I also agree with you. Thank you for pointing that out. @Lee :)

Comment: Not really @GreenFox, as lets take your example. if you were to just include `col-xs-12 col-sm-6` and then removed the other two above, no matter how larger the screen would get, the classes would stay at half value. There is no need to add anything, or get a custom css involved at all.

Comment: I know, I get you. But my point is what if you need `col-md-4` and/or `col-lg-3`? Again it's just my opinion that it is better (for me at least) to include these classes in case you need an immediate changes.@Lee

Comment: Mr. @Lee I quoted your comment and added it to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @GreenFox Then you add them when and where you need them... You don't always need to use every sizing class, every time, all of the time. Your response to the initial question, didn't need to include them all, and you said 'Use this'. I just felt as though that was a bit unnecessary.

Comment: @GreenFox thanks for you answer. Clearly you spend a lot of time for my question. I replaced my Bootstrap file so I solved the problem. Anyway, thank you for your effort.